# join query on one-to-one Grails domain using GORM with parameters

Tags: oracle, grails, grails-orm

I have a two Grails `domain` class, let say:

```
class Hero {
    String name
    Float level

    Familiar familiar
}

class Familiar {
    String name
    Integer raceId
}
```

Now, what I want is to retrieve all `Hero` having `Familiar` with the name similar to a given `String`, for *example*: `"hachiko"`. To do that using `SQL`, all I need is to perform a query similar to this:

```
SELECT h.name, h.level
FROM HERO h JOIN FAMILIAR f ON h.id = f.ownerId
WHERE f.name LIKE '%hachiko%'
```

But how can I do that on `Grails`? This is my code:

```
String filter = "hachiko"
def hero = Hero.executeQuery(
    "SELECT h.name, h.level FROM HERO h JOIN h.familiar WHERE h.id = " +
    "h.familiar.ownerId and h.familiar.name LIKE :filter",
    [filter, "%$filter%"]
)
```

Would this work? Should I create those `static` properties (`hasOne`, `belongsTo`), and where should I place them? Because so far, without those `static` properties, I'm receiving an `error` message:

> `ORA-00904: "HERO0_"."FAMILIAR_ID": invalid identifier`

And having those `static` properties added, I got this:

> `org.hibernate.MappingException: hasOne property [Hero.familiar] is not bidirectional. Specify the other side of the relationship!`

Their relationship is *optional* one-to-one. (e.g. A `Hero` can have at most one `Familiar`), and the `id` of the `Familiar` is the same of it's `Hero`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [createCriteria](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html) for that

```
String filter = "hachiko"
def hero = Hero.createCriteria().list {
    familiar {
        like('name', filter)
    }    
}
```

Comment: Do I need to add some `static` properties or not?

Comment: You already have familiar in the hero domain. So you can access familiar from hero. If you want bidirectional relationship then you can define `static` property otherwise your current implementation is sufficient to fulfill your current requirement.

Comment: Will it still be applicable even if `Familiar` is `nullable`?

Comment: If familiar is null then that records will not be return by this criteria because they are not satisfying this.

Comment: It still returns `ORA-00904: "HERO0_"."FAMILIAR_ID": invalid identifier`.

Comment: Above criteria works for me. Don't know why you are getting error.