# Flatten a nested Grails Domain object

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Concerning to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30883444/4043409), having this set of Grails `domain` classes:

```
class Hero {
    String name
    Float level

    static hasOne = [familiar: Familiar]
}

class Familiar {
    String name
    Integer raceId

    static belongsTo = [hero: Hero]
}
```

How can I change the result of querying `Hero` from:

```
[
    name: "Emphraim",
    level: 99.0,
    familiar: {
        name: "Mhyrr",
        raceId: 1
    }
]
```

to a flat one:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Ephraim"
        "level": 99.0,
        "familiar_name": "Mhyrr"
        "familiar_raceId": 1
    }
]
```

without mapping it one by one to a new `HashMap`? I query `Hero` class using this code:

```
def hero = Hero.find {
    eq("name", "Ephraim")
}
```

Comment: If you want to customize the way domain classes or collections of domain classes are rendered as JSON then I recommend you read up on customized marshallers. This topic has been discussed countless times here on SO and there are lots of blog posts related to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Joshua mentioned, you would need a custom marshaller. There are different ways to do it but I would recommend [this plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/marshallers)